# How to get the number of elements (size) from List of WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify the number of elements (in this case links) in the sub menu of the webpage with an Assert of great than 3 elements before clicking one of the links, but the Assert errors with a size of zero.

```
@Test
public void top3NewsStoriesHoverTest()
{

    WebElement hoverNews = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class^='_3EBT0 _2m2om uVwkS']")));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(hoverNews).build().perform();

    List<WebElement> subMenuTopStories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class^='_1yCjv'] [class^='dHmN_']"));

    //System.out.println(subMenuTopStories.size());
    assertEquals(subMenuTopStories.size(), greaterThan(3));

    WebElement subMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[class^='dHmN_']")));
    subMenu.click();

}
```

Comment: What does `subMenuTopStories.size()` prints? `class^='_1yCjv'` and `class^='dHmN_'` looks dynamic to me.

Comment: Whether the submenu links will be displayed after clicking on the menu , else, just mousehover action alone enough to display the submenu links?

Comment: DebanjanB:  The 'subMenuTopStories.size' prints out "0" at the moment.  And the combination of `class^='_1yCjv'` and `class^='dHmN_'` capture three sub menu elements.   I want to verify the number of those elements before I click one of them.

Comment: @Rainier As I suspected we won't be able to make out a _List_ based on `class^='_1yCjv'` and `class^='dHmN_'` as these classes are [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) based. We have to either look into the other _attributes_, _parent nodes_ or combination of both. Can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing for equality between an integer and a matcher. What you probably want is Hamcrest's `assertThat`, not `assertEquals` (assuming you're using hamcrest, which it looks like you're doing)

Comment: I am using running my test with testNG. Can I use assertThat?  I thought that was only supported by Junit?

Comment: I don't know TestNG, but you need to use an assert function that's compatible with whatever your `greaterThan` returns. I can't find any `greaterThan`in the TestNG docs, so I still suspect it's from hamcrest. So if you're using hamcrest, you should be using hamcrest's assertThat, which will work fine in TestNG (or any testing framework)